# Not Duplicate :: How to sort and filter inside a groupby in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
{
"document_id": "firstDoc",
"date_changed" : ISODate("2017-07-26T17:52:37.061Z"),
"enabled": false
},
{
"document_id": "firstDoc",
"date_changed" : ISODate("2018-07-26T17:52:37.061Z"),
"enabled": true
},
{
"document_id": "secondDoc",
"date_changed" : ISODate("2017-07-26T17:52:37.061Z"),
"enabled": true
},
{
"document_id": "secondDoc",
"date_changed" : ISODate("2018-07-26T17:52:37.061Z"),
"enabled": true
}
```

I want to `groupby` `document_id` 1st, then for each set get the document with max `date_changed`, and then filter document `"enabled": true`

So the expected output is:

```
{
    "document_id": "secondDoc",
    "date_changed" : ISODate("2018-07-26T17:52:37.061Z"),
    "enabled": true
    },
{
    "document_id": "firstDoc",
    "date_changed" : ISODate("2018-07-26T17:52:37.061Z"),
    "enabled": true
    }
```

Why other question answer cannot solve my problem: 
In the other question only a simple groupby and count is needed.

But here we have to group first, then apply sort for each grouped section and pick the one which have latest date and then apply a filter. As far as I know we can't use sort inside group.

I have tried this:

```
var myCursor = db.configurations.aggregate([
{$group: {'_id':'$document_id',
          'date':{$max: 'date_changed'}
          }
}
]);
while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
    var eachDoc = myCursor.next();
    printjson(eachDoc.config.booknow.shoppingList.enabled);
    printjson(eachDoc.document_id);
}
```

But it is giving error:
`TypeError: myCursor.hasNext is not a function (shell):1`

**DB version is 2.4.13**
Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: @Ashh can you please explain how this is a duplicate with the one you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The error you shared is an issue more likely with your environment or how you're executing the code. Execute your code line by line and you'd figure out the problem in your environment.

Your query is correct. You may want to put some null checks for the line `printjson(eachDoc.config...` but that's not related to the error you receive.